# MPI_CART_CREATE period argument

Tags: c, mpi

I kind of understand what this routine does, in the sense that it creates a Cartesian coordinate system for processors over the actual scheme, but I don't understand what the "periods" argument does.

I'm currently setting it all to 0, but I'd like to know what periods are, can't find anything online on the subject.

Here's the signature :

```
int MPI_Cart_create(
  MPI_Comm comm_old,
  int ndims,
  int *dims,
  int *periods,
  int reorder,
  MPI_Comm *comm_cart
);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The parameter `periods[n]` specifies whether the `n`th dimension is periodic, that is whether coordinate `0` in dimension `n` is a neighbour of  coordinate `n_max`.

Some examples for visualization: If `ndims == 1`, then having the single dimension's `period` being `false` means the topology looks like a line of workers, whereas if you set it to `true`, you get a circle (ring topology).

With `ndims == 2` and the `periods` being false, false you get a square, with true, false you get a cylinder (wrap the square sheet around one dimension) - and with true, true you get a torus (doughnut).

Comment: Hey us2012, my sample program works neatly, but I was wondering something. I have 24 cpu's at my disposal, which MPI routine could I use to split them into three groups of 8 where each group have distinct ranks 0 to 7. Is that even possible? I assume I would need to use separate MPI_comm's to get the proper ranks of each group.

Comment: @Pat Does this help? http://static.msi.umn.edu/tutorial/scicomp/general/MPI/communicator.html Look at the general description and at example 1.